# Running a Ping.SendAsync with status message

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ping

I am creating a reporting system to check the status of blades. I know the code below works, but it is painstakingly slow. I looked up information about running Ping.SendAsync and it looks promising, but it doesn't run a status report on the ping unless it is in a handler. The problem with that, is that i need to access other objects in the function to change the webpage correctly.

```
protected void RadGridDellBlade_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == GridItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == GridItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            thing1 t1 = new thing1();
            BladeRunnerDataAccess td = new BladeRunnerDataAccess(t1);
            try
            {
                Image icon = (Image)e.Item.FindControl("Dell_imgIcon");
                BladeWorkstation blade = (BladeWorkstation)e.Item.DataItem;
                Ping pingSender = new Ping();
                PingReply reply = pingSender.Send(blade.IPAddress);

                switch (reply.Status)
                {
                    case IPStatus.Success:
                        icon.ImageUrl = "~/Images/GreenIcon.png";
                        break;
                    case IPStatus.TimedOut:
                        icon.ImageUrl = "~/Images/RedIcon.png";
                        break;
                    default:
                        icon.ImageUrl = "~/Images/GrayIcon.png";
                        break;
                }
                Image Dell_osbit = (Image)e.Item.FindControl("Dell_OSbit");
                switch (blade.BladeOSID)
                {
                    case 1:
                        Dell_osbit.ImageUrl = "~/Images/xp.png";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Dell_osbit.ImageUrl = "~/Images/32bit.png";
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Dell_osbit.ImageUrl = "~/Images/64bit.png";
                        break;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
            finally
            {
                t1.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

This code works but runs all 250 blades one at a time and takes minutes. Is there a way to do this parallel or with threading, and keep the status check as well? I appreciate any help!!

Comment: This guy used PingAcync to do what you're looking to do.  Not sure if he's using .NET or straight Power Shell, but I stumbled across it looking for a solution in Power Shell.  Since the two are very similar, you might be able to find the solution you're looking for in his script. One of the cool features is that there is a status indicator when I run it in ISE.  I have not tried it outside of the ISE though. https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Fast-asynchronous-ping-IP-d0a5cf0e/

Answer (score 0):

Lacking a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows what you've tried, I can't guarantee a complete and accurate solution. But, you certainly can combine the older event-based model of `Ping.SendAsync()` with `async`/`await` and turn your code into a reasonably good asynchronous implementation.

I gather from the name of your method that you are doing this work as each item is bound to a container control. So you haven't shown us the actual loop that does all 250 items. I'm assuming that it will be sufficient to run each call of the event handler asynchronously. To that end:

```
protected async void RadGridDellBlade_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == GridItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == GridItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        thing1 t1 = new thing1();
        BladeRunnerDataAccess td = new BladeRunnerDataAccess(t1);
        try
        {
            Image icon = (Image)e.Item.FindControl("Dell_imgIcon");
            BladeWorkstation blade = (BladeWorkstation)e.Item.DataItem;
            Ping pingSender = new Ping();
            TaskCompletionSource<PingReply> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<PingReply>();

            pingSender.PingCompleted += (s, e2) => tcs.SetResult(e2.Reply);
            pingSender.SendAsync(blade.IPAddress, null);
            PingReply reply = await tcs.Task;

            switch (reply.Status)
            {
                case IPStatus.Success:
                    icon.ImageUrl = "~/Images/GreenIcon.png";
                    break;
                case IPStatus.TimedOut:
                    icon.ImageUrl = "~/Images/RedIcon.png";
                    break;
                default:
                    icon.ImageUrl = "~/Images/GrayIcon.png";
                    break;
            }
            Image Dell_osbit = (Image)e.Item.FindControl("Dell_OSbit");
            switch (blade.BladeOSID)
            {
                case 1:
                    Dell_osbit.ImageUrl = "~/Images/xp.png";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Dell_osbit.ImageUrl = "~/Images/32bit.png";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Dell_osbit.ImageUrl = "~/Images/64bit.png";
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            t1.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

As far as the object that raises the event and calls the above handler, the handler will complete its work as soon as you reach the `await tcs.Task;` statement (assuming the ping hasn't completed by then). Once the ping completes, execution of the method will resume with the valid value of the `PingReply` now available.

Naturally, until the ping completes, each item in the collection will have whatever default state it started with. Presumably this is acceptable. If not, you'll have to create some intermediate state to display while the ping is in progress.

Comment: Wow thank you very much for the help! It looks like it will work perfectly. I apologize for not posting all the code. I'm building an API for this and the code is very long and this is just a small part of it. I also didn't include/changed some things for security reasons.
I am getting an error at  `pingSender.PingCompleted += (s, e) => tcs.SetResult(e.Reply);`
for the "e" variable. it says, "cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter"
How can i get around it?

Comment: _"I apologize for not posting all the code"_ -- no worries. I mean, we do prefer that here on Stack Overflow, but deficiencies in a question really only hurt the person posting the question. You'll get better answers with better questions. E.g., the error message you're getting, if I'd been able to actually compile your code example, I'd not have overlooked that the method already has an `e` variable. You can fix the error by changing that line of code to `pingSender.PingCompleted += (s, e2) => tcs.SetResult(e2.Reply);` (or, use whatever unique name for the second lambda parameter you like.